# Detecting controller movement in same direction as VR button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions, vectormath

I'm working on a VR project and I'm struggling to do something that should not be that hard, but I really am bad at math :x

What I want to do, is have "physical" buttons on the world that I can push with my finger to press/unpress it, this part works really well and the feeling is perfect, BUT :

Currently, to "push" the button, I'm using the z delta position of my controller, so I can't push button from the top for example, because I would need the y delta.

I'm trying to be able to have buttons facing any direction, and be able to push them using the right axis of my controller, but can't get my head around it :x

I'd need to be able to push the button depending on it's position/rotation.

I don't know if it's really understandable (probably not), maybe I just missed something really obvious.

Here is my code for my button, the enum part is probably useless, I'm just trying things lol

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class JVRButton : MonoBehaviour, IJVRFingerInteract
{

    [SerializeField] private Vector3 pressedPosition;
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 defaultPosition;
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 unpressPosition;

    [SerializeField] private LinearDragNormal direction;

    public bool Pressed { get; private set; }
    public event Action<bool> OnStateChange;

    private bool _changedState;
    private Transform _transform;
    private Vector3 _tmp;
    private float _delay;

    private float _delta; 

    private void Awake()
    {
        _transform = transform;
        _transform.localPosition = Pressed ? pressedPosition : defaultPosition;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        _delay += Time.deltaTime;
        if (_delay < 0.1f) return;

        // "Spring" effect
        _transform.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(_transform.localPosition, Pressed ? pressedPosition : defaultPosition, Time.deltaTime / 2);
    }

    public void JVRFingerInteract(JVRFinger jvrFinger)
    {
        Vector3 test = Quaternion.FromToRotation(jvrFinger.transform.forward, _transform.forward).eulerAngles;

        Debug.Log(test);

        switch(direction)
        {
            case LinearDragNormal.XPositive:
                _delta = Mathf.Min(jvrFinger.JVRController.DeltaPositionLocal.z, 0);
                break;
            case LinearDragNormal.XNegative:
                _delta = Mathf.Max(jvrFinger.JVRController.DeltaPositionLocal.z, 0);
                break;
            case LinearDragNormal.YPositive:
                _delta = Mathf.Max(jvrFinger.JVRController.DeltaPositionLocal.y, 0);
                break;
            case LinearDragNormal.YNegative:
                _delta = Mathf.Min(jvrFinger.JVRController.DeltaPositionLocal.y, 0);
                break;
             case LinearDragNormal.ZPositive:
                _delta = Mathf.Min(jvrFinger.JVRController.DeltaPositionLocal.x, 0);
                break;
            case LinearDragNormal.ZNegative:
                _delta = Mathf.Max(jvrFinger.JVRController.DeltaPositionLocal.x, 0);
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }

        MoveButton(Pressed ? unpressPosition : pressedPosition);
    }

    private void MoveButton(Vector3 position)
    {
        if (_changedState && _delay < 0.5f) return;
        _delay = 0;
        _changedState = false;            
        _tmp = _transform.localPosition;
        _tmp = Vector3.MoveTowards(_tmp, position, _delta);
        if (_tmp.x < position.x) _tmp.x = position.x;
        if (_tmp.y < position.y) _tmp.y = position.y;
        if (_tmp.z < position.z) _tmp.z = position.z;
        _transform.localPosition = _tmp;

        if (_transform.localPosition == pressedPosition)
        {
            Pressed = true;
            _changedState = true;
            OnStateChange?.Invoke(Pressed);
        }
        else if (_transform.localPosition == unpressPosition)
        {
            Pressed = false;
            _changedState = true;
            OnStateChange?.Invoke(Pressed);
        }
    }    
}

public enum LinearDragNormal
{
    XPositive,
    XNegative,
    YPositive,
    YNegative,
    ZPositive,
    ZNegative
}
```

JVRFingerInteract is called every frame my finger is touching the button, I'm simply doing a overlapsphere in my Finger to get interactable objects.

The pushing axis of the button is the button's local Z axis, and positive Z points **out of** the surface of the button.

Comment: Could you reduce your code or mark clearly where exactly you calculate that `Z delta` which should rather be any vector in 3D ? Can't you simply use the button's `Vector3.forward` or `Vector3.up` vector for the possible movement direction and also check where the finger position is moved only on this direction -> [Vector3.Project](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Project.html)

Comment: jvrFinger.JVRController.DeltaPositionLocal is my local delta (i've a world one too, need it for other things), it is calculated elsewhere and works fine

Comment: I'm not quite getting why u are doing 3D button clicks like this. Look into Raycasting.

Comment: It's on VR, I've a physical finger, I can't really raycast

Comment: @Musaka yeah raycasting is not what you want to do in this case ... OP doesn't want to shoot the buttons from distance but interact with them like a Touch

Comment: "I'd need to be able to push the button depending on it's position/rotation.", can you please elaborate more on this. What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to have your buttons always looking at you?

Comment: I want to be able to put a button anywhere, in any rotation, and use the correct delta axis to move it. button are just translating as I push them

Comment: If I understood better this time, you are trying to see if you are pushing the buttons with axis, if that's the case I would take a different approach. Example: get the vector from you(player or the hand) to the center of the button and normalize it (to get a directional vector), and then get a vector of your hand movement (also get the direction), and if the directions are withing some similar range(magic number)/ if they are the same direction, then the player is pushing the button. Of course the collision stuff stays so they can't push the button from far away.

Comment: I found something, now it work when my button is facing World X and World Y, but not World -Z : Vector3 jvrPos = jvrFinger.JVRController.DeltaPositionLocal;
        _delta = (_forward.x * jvrPos.z + _forward.y * -jvrPos.y + _forward.z * jvrPos.x);

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the solution by trying, I don't understand HOW and WHY it works, but it does...

```
_delta = (_forward.x * jvrPos.z + _forward.y * -jvrPos.y + _forward.z * -jvrPos.x);
if (_delta < 0) _delta = 0;
```

_forward being the button forward, and jvrPos being the local delta of my controller/finger

Comment: If you do 
`Vector3 transformedJvrPos = new Vector3(jvrPos.z, -jvrPos.y, -jvrPos.x);` `Debug.DrawRay(fingerPosition, transformedJvrPos.normalized * 2.0, Color.magenta, 0.1f);` does a line get drawn from the finger in the direction it's moving?  I'm trying to understand more about what the transformation accomplishes.

Comment: I don't see anything being drawn :x

Comment: Hmm, maybe the duration or length is too short or its being hidden behind something. Try `DrawRay(fingerPosition, transformedJvrPos.normalized * 10.0, Color.magenta, 1.0f, false); ` Also make sure `fingerPosition` is in world space coordinates (same as if you had `fingerTransform.position`).

Comment: Also, make sure [you have enabled `Gizmos`](https://answers.unity.com/storage/temp/58608-gizmos.png) if you're watching the game view.

Comment: Ok my bad, didn't have gizmos on, so it basically draw in the inverse direction on where i'm going. If I move my finger to the right, it draw to the left and so on

Comment: Since `DrawRay` draws in world space, that seems like `transformedJvrPos` is the negative of the finger's world delta.  That means using my answer as `Vector3 d = new Vector3(-jvrPos.z, jvrPos.y, jvrPos.x);` `_delta = Vector3.Dot(d, -_forward);` should also work. I'm curious what happens if you take your value for `fingerWorldDelta` and do `Debug.DrawRay(fingerPosition, fingerWorldDelta.normalized * 2.0, Color.blue, 0.1f);`?  It should point in the direction the finger is moving.

Comment: It does, that's actually what I made the WorldDelta for ! I use it for some interaction, and for some other (like climbing a ladder "physically", the world delta is useless because the player is climbing thus Y delta is wrong)

Comment: That's the idea though, if the player is climbing down the ladder, then shouldn't holding the finger in the same local position (such that the finger is moving down in world space) be able to press the button down?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the surface of your button faces the button's local `up` direction:

[image: local axes of button]

Then you can use a dot product between the button's `up` in world space and the delta in world space to determine how much the finger is moving against that direction:

```
Vector3 worldFingerDelta;
Transform buttonTransform;

float deltaInButtonDown = Vector3.Dot(worldFingerDelta, 
        -buttonTransform.up);

// when deltainButtonDown is positive, the finger is moving in the 
// same direction as "pushing the button" 
// When it is negative, the finger is moving in the opposite direction.
// The magnitude of deltaInButtonDown is how much the finger is 
// moving in that direction.
```

[image: local axes of button]

If a different local direction is pointing out of the surface of the button, such as its negative `forward`, you would just use the corresponding local vector in world space:

[image: negative forward is pointing out of the button]

```
float deltaInButtonDown = Vector3.Dot(worldFingerDelta, 
        buttonTransform.forward); // negatives cancel out
```

Also, if the surface the button is on is moving in world space, you'll want to use `Vector3.Dot(worldFingerDelta - worldButtonSurfaceDelta, buttonTransform.forward);` in order to allow for things like the button pressing itself by moving into a still finger.

---

About your answer....

> ```
> _delta = (_forward.x * jvrPos.z + _forward.y * -jvrPos.y 
>         + _forward.z * -jvrPos.x);
> if (_delta < 0) _delta = 0;
> ```
>
> `_forward` being the button forward, and `jvrPos` being the local delta of my controller/finger

As far as the vector math goes, you're doing a dot product between the button's forward and the local delta after some kind of inversion/reflection transformation is applied to it. So another way to write your answer is this:

> ```
> new Vector3 vec = new Vector3(jvrPos.z, -jvrPos.y, -jvrPos.x);
> _delta = Vector3.Dot(vec, buttonTransform.forward);
> ```

As we discovered in the comments of your answer, that transformation, based on the world rotation of the parent of the controller, turns your local delta into the negative of the world delta. So by taking the negative of what you have for the vector and making that negative in the `Dot` call, another way to write your answer is this:

> ```
> new Vector3 calculatedWorldFingerDelta = new Vector3(-jvrPos.z, jvrPos.y, jvrPos.x);
> _delta = Vector3.Dot(-calculatedWorldFingerDelta, buttonTransform.forward);
> ```

And since the dot product of A and -B  equals the dot product of -A and B, your answer is equivalent to:

> ```
> new Vector3 calculatedWorldFingerDelta = new Vector3(-jvrPos.z, jvrPos.y, jvrPos.x);
> _delta = Vector3.Dot(calculatedWorldFingerDelta, -buttonTransform.forward);
> ```

Which, if `calculatedWorldFingerDelta` equals `worldFingerDelta`, is the same formula above for a button with the positive z direction pointing out of the surface of the button.

I would use `worldFingerDelta` directly because if the world rotation or position of the parent of the finger changes, then the transformation you're using now won't be guaranteed to give you `calculatedWorldFingerDelta` that equals `worldFingerDelta`, and your answer won't work anymore.

Comment: Actually it works in every single direction/rotation, that was the problem I was facing but with what I did it's working. The "push axis" of the button is the Z axis. I tried to do something with Vector3.Dot before my solution but couldn't find something working

Comment: And btw, the main problem using controller/finger world delta instead of local is that the player can move, thus altering the world delta, which gives unexpected results sometimes

Comment: @Jichael if the player's head (or whatever) being moved alters the delta of the controller, that doesn't sound like the "world delta" at all - that sounds like it's local to the player's head (or whatever). I think we're using different terminology. Can you include what you mean by "local delta" (how you calculate it) in your answer and/or include what you mean  by "world delta" (how you calculate it) in the question?

Comment: @Jichael Also, which direction along local Z is pushing "into" the button?

Comment: For me, LocalDelta is the difference of localPosition since the last frame, WorldDelta is the difference of position. Didn't understand your second question. I'll do the ray and post it as an edit

Comment: @Jichael my second question is if you select the button gameobject, is the blue [transform gizmo](https://answers.unity.com/storage/temp/139280-capture.png) arrow (the local positive `z` direction) pointing *out of* the surface of the button (like the up (green arrow) in my [first diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1fiX.png)) or is it pointing *into* the surface of the button like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ekmbe.png)?

Comment: It is pointing out of the button, like in your diagram (the green arrow)

Comment: @Jichael I updated this answer to explain why your other answer works (it's equivalent to mine when the parent of the controller/finger is of a certain world rotation) Also, did you actually try my answer when you said that it gives unexpected results sometimes? Or were you only speaking hypothetically?